# Getting error when running Point Cloud Library tutorial

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am running this tutorial here:-
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/matrix_transform.php#matrix-transform

but I get this error

```
[pcl::PLYReader] cube.ply:1: parse error: couldn't read the magic string
[pcl::PLYReader::read] problem parsing header!
[pcl::PLYReader::read] problem parsing header!
Error loading point cloud cube.ply
```

I am  a complete newbie and I have no idea about this.
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

It looks the .ply you are using is not correctly formated. Try loading a .pcd file.

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of research, I found the cube.ply

https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/ply/cube.ply

Just save this file and run it.It works!

Comment: We've updated the tutorial text with a link to the "cube.ply" file.

Comment: Thanks! I love the Pcl library :)